# How can I execute an add to Cloud Firestore in Cloud Functions through routes in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a document in my Cloud Firestore db by using following code:

**Backend:**

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const chatrooms = express();
chatrooms.use(cors);
let chatroomsEndpoint = require('./chatroomsEndpoint')

chatrooms.post('/', chatroomsEndpoint.createChatroom); // Create new chatroom
exports.chatrooms = functions.https.onRequest(chatrooms);
```

chatroomsEndpoint.js:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const chatroomsCollection = db.collection("chatrooms");

exports.createChatroom = function (req, res) {
    chatroomsCollection.add(req.body)
    .then(resul => {
        console.log('Successfully added chatroom');
        return res.status(201).send(true);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error creating new chatroom', error)
        return res.send(false);
    })
}
```

**Frontend:**

chat.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }

async create() {
    const userA = 'FeuzErzVIfTXKVvuagBzLvGcETK2'; 
    const userB = 'jmYZlOIjQkbOPnlVt54cfsdvJFb2';

    const data = {
      userA,
      userB,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      messages: []
    };
    await this.http.put(`${this.apiUrl}/chatrooms`, data);
    return   this.router.navigate([`chats/XvlQIXo650VFhjMsOlf5`]) && console.log('return is executed');
  }
```

chatroom-list.component.html:

```
<button class="button is-info" (click)="chatService.create()">Create New Chat</button>
```

My problem is that after clicking on the 'Create New Chat' Button I just get the console.log('return is executed') and navigate to 'chats/XvlQIXo650VFhjMsOlf5', but no document is created in Firestore and my Functions don't get triggered.

Also there is no error on the client side and no error on the Firebase Console (under Functions/Logs). I just want to try creating a document with the route. I tried to find help on other posts, but I'm not even sure what kind of problem I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the cloud function only through the application I will suggest you take a look at https.onCall cloud functions you can make a call directly from your Angular App.

Please refer to the following link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

If you are using AngularFire package you can call the onCall functions with the httpsCallable method in the package.

I was not able to find why your above code is not working. Are you calling the function with **https** package? Could you provide the error or log of the HTTP call?

Comment: I updated chat.service.ts. I'm using HttpClient. Do you mean that?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer. Could you confirm if your API endpoint is working when called outside the application?

Comment: Yes, I can. I used it with Postman and it worked. That's why I wonder. Nothing happens, not even a error log on the client side, if I try to trigger my API endpoint.

Comment: @ConstantinBeer thanks for that. Can you check if this is a CORS error? is the endpoint http or https , Could you also post the import statement for the  HttpClient class?

Comment: I updated the import statement for the HttpClient. How can I check if it's a CORS error if I don't get any error logs? Is there another way to check that?

Comment: Can you check if you are sending the headers properly? The put call should return you an observable subscribe to it and see what error or content it prints.

Comment: OMG It worked! I was able to trigger the function. It was the subscribe(). Thank you a lot. Think I have to read more about subscribe and observables :)